# Related Objects in User.layout Metadata on Winter '14

Tags: metadata-api, winter14

What's going on with the `layouts/User-User Layout.layout` metadata file?  I have scripts that snapshot all of my metadata every day.  Ever since we upgraded to Winter '14, the following lines are appearing or disappearing every day.  One day they're included in the metadata file, and the next day they're gone, alternating constantly.  Anyone know what's going on with this?

```
<relatedObjects>UserRoleId</relatedObjects>
<relatedObjects>ProfileId</relatedObjects>
<relatedObjects>DelegatedApproverId</relatedObjects>
<relatedObjects>ManagerId</relatedObjects>
<relatedObjects>ContactId</relatedObjects>
<relatedObjects>AccountId</relatedObjects>
<relatedObjects>CallCenterId</relatedObjects>
<relatedObjects>ProfilePhotoId</relatedObjects>
<relatedObjects>WorkspaceId</relatedObjects>
```

Comment: I don't have an answer as to why but I can definitely acknowledge the behavior. We have the same setup which runs hourly and checks things in to Git. Over the last couple of days (weeks?) we've observed the same as you're describing. Makes it very difficult to see when "real" changes happen to the object...

Comment: Same issue here. The same elements also appear in the Layout metadata for User as well

Comment: Has this settled down, or is it continuing to happen?

Comment: Yup, it's still going on.

Comment: Has anyone logged a case with salesforce.com about this oddity? Or has anyone seen any differences since Spring '14 (went live on NA1 last week)?

Comment: I think this illustrates the quantic property of the force.com platform : observing it actually changes its status !  :)

Answer (score 2):

It would be the best to log a case with Salesforce.com Developer Support

Answer (score 0):

Are you guys still experiencing these issues?
We're using [Copado Deployer](http://www.copa.do) from the AppExchange to perform backups and have not noticed anything out of the ordinary.